# Magento get store Name in a file which is in root directory

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, store-view, store-id

I have a file assume abc.php in multisite set up.

If I hit this using url :`domain1.com/abc.php`, I should get store name of domain1 and if I hit it using `domain2.com/abc.php`, I should get store name of domain2. I am using the below code:

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();
```

`domain1.com` being by default frontstore, when I hit `domain2.com/abc.php` I get store name of domain1 always. How do I get store specific information in a while placed in root folder?

Answer (score 2):

You can try bellow code :

```
require_once("app/Mage.php");
echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();
```

Comment: Doesn't work :(

Comment: sorry I did not read your requirement properly. Actually this way you cannot get other store name except default store name . for this you have to set **$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] and $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']** for each store. then you can use the above code to get store name.

Comment: How do I use it to keep it dynamic always? As in sometimes we may use website or store for run type...how do I always get the correct store name then?

Comment: If  **MAGE_RUN_TYPE** is website then it gives default store name of that website and if **MAGE_RUN_TYPE** is store then it gives the current store name. For other than default store you have to pass the **store code** through url and set it as current store.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code in the start of your page

```
$magento_path = __DIR__;
require "{$magento_path}/app/Mage.php";
```